# Spring Sample Application

Tags: java, spring

Could anyone point me towards some good, detailed, sample Spring applications?

Ideally those with good test coverage!

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the sample projects from the SpringFramework Subversion repository:
https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/

Answer (score 1):

Demo project based on Spring's Petclinic that aims to integrate various frameworks: Spring MVC, Spring Webflow, Freemarker, Sitemesh, Hibernate, Acegi, DWR.here There will be three subprojects that differ in complexity and should cover most web application requirements.

https://code.google.com/p/petclinicplus/

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Spring's PetClinic.

Or another good option is to test Spring's tutorials that are available from the dashboard inside [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts).

Answer (score 0):

[Spring by Example](http://www.springbyexample.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial can help you: http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/
It's a simple app developed step by step.